# getURL excel UDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

So in reference to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560817/cell-reference-with-hyperlinked-text) I asked about displaying text and its hyperlink by referencing it in another cell, I found someone wrote this macro command for excel to retrieve the URL address:

```
Public Function GetURL(c As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetURL = c.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

This basically allows me to use `=getURL(A1)` to get the URL of the text in cell A1, even if that cell contains a text with the hyperlink attached (because the `=HYPERLINK` command brings the text itself and tried to create a URL out of it, which of course won't work).

My question is how do I actually use it?
I have attempted to enter the following functions:
`=HYPERLINK(=getURL(general!M5), Test)`
`=HYPERLINK(=getURL(general!M5), [Test])`

So I wanted to get the URL from cell M5 in the "general" worksheet and use it as a hyperlink for the text "test".

That doesn't seem to work and I can't understand why. When I enter these commands, I get an error message that the function contains an error.
I sometimes manage to avoid the error message by playing with the cell type between general and text, but even when there is no error message, it doesn't display what I wanted it to and just displays the function itself.

Any ideas?

[This is what the Macro looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfUyF.jpg)

Comment: at first try to use "test" within `hyperlink`, otherwise Excel thinks `test` is a variable. The macro itself seems ok.

Comment: Well I used "test" as a test to see if the URL is transferred correctly.
I aim for a final solution of =HYPERLINK(=getURL(general!M5), [M5]

That way I will copy the cell exactly as it is, both text AND hyperlink... I really don't know why EXCEL uses such inefficient algorithms for its basic functionality. When I type =A1 in a cell, my expectation is that A1 will be copied EXACTLY as it is, both text AND hyperlink.
Instead =A1 only copies the text, while =HYPERLINK copies the text and tries to use it as a URL (which I suppose is meant for cells which contain the URL as a string).

Comment: @MátéJuhász that was my first thought as well, but I think the weird notation is what made us miss the extra `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the `=` within your hyperlink formula

```
=HYPERLINK(getURL(C1),B1)
```

Takes the address from C1 and the text from B1.

Same way using other sheets as references

```
=HYPERLINK(getURL(Sheet3!C1),Sheet3!B1)
```

Comment: Thanx, but that doesn't seem to have solved the issue either I'm afraid.
Here is the latest input:
=HYPERLINK(GetURL(General!M5), General!M5)
And the output is:
#NAME?

Now there is some progress - it recognizes that there is indeed a link there, because when the mouse is over the cell it becomes the little pointing finger, but when I click it nothing happens, and the text is still missing :\

Comment: Let's go back to basics. In A1 put a link to google, named whatever. In A2 type google. Now in A3 use `=HYPERLINK(getURL(A1),A2)` - what happens? Have you made other changes like changing the name of the module?

Comment: Thanx, but this isn't what I'm trying to do.
In A1 I have a text which is ALSO a hyperlink (i.e. right click -> hyper-link -> add hyperlink).
Now I want that cell to be displayed AS IS (i.e. the text as a hyperlink) to a cell in another spreadsheet.

When I use your system I indeed get a text with the hyperlink attached, but that doesn't help me because the original data isn't in different cells.

For a very short time in ONE computer I have managed to use =HYPERLINK(getURL(A1), A1) and it actually worked for 24 hours, then it stopped working again. No idea why.

Comment: Using `=HYPERLINK(getURL(A1), A1)` will work.

Comment: I know it suppose to work, but it doesn't. That's the exact command I entered and it returns "#NAME?"

Comment: Make sure you are using proper notations - make sure the UDF hasn't changed, make sure it still works (the on error resume will never stop if it breaks), make sure your module is still the same name

Comment: Ok, it seems that for an unknown reason, =geturl was added to the name of one of the workseets (it didn't appear in EXCEL, only in the VB menu), which caused the calculation to break. Once I removed it from the name, it started working again.